# Points for thousand mark and decimal mark

Tags: python, points

I have a messed up txt-file, with points as a thousand mark (1.000 or 19.329) and as a decimal mark (10000.3). Two example lines:

```
John;1.952;2003;20.365;1.214 

Ryan;2.342;2002;3045.3;345
```

I want to remove the point for the thousand mark and keep the points for the decimals. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: How can you distinguish between the two cases?  In other words, should 1.234 be 1,234 or 1.234?

Comment: Is there always exactly one decimal place? Is there another rule that lets *you* know which is which? Explain it and we'll tell you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never have exactly three decimal places after the decimal point, the following will do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\.(\d\d\d(\D|$))", r"\1", "200.000.5")
'200000.5'
```

The regexp removes a dot if it is followed by exactly three digits. It won't match fewer digits (since it looks for three `\d`), and it won't match more since it looks for a non-digit after them (`\D`).

Comment: Thanks, mate. I was thinking on much harder solutions.

Comment: Regular expressions are the cat's pyjamas.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that decimals are always only one digit:

```
line = "Ryan;2.342;2002;3045.3;345"
parts = line.split(";")

#Remove the name.
name = parts.pop(0) 

def fix(part):
    decimal = ""
    if part[-2] == '.':
        decimal = part[-2:]
        part = part[:-2]
    part = part.replace('.',',')
    return part+decimal

parts = [fix(part) for part in parts]
line = name+";"+";".join(parts)
```

I don't think there's a very easy way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was thinking in this direction as well, but alexis' solution is a much easier.

Comment: I have to agree. Much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the precision of your numbers. How many decimal places do the numbers in the text file have? If it's less than 3, then it should be trivial. If it's 3 or more, I'm not sure it can be done without at least *some* error.